# How to know what kind of EJB is in runtime?

Tags: java, ejb

How to know what kind of EJB is the returned object by a lookup in runtime?

With only know if is a stateful is good for me.

```
bound = new InitialContext().lookup(lookup);
if(isStateful(bound)){...}
```

My current Application server is a JBoss AS 6.1

Answer (score 1):

It depends... do you use the annotations [`Stateful`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateful.html) and [`Stateless`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html)?

```
final Class<?> clazz = bound.getClass();
if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Stateful.class)) {
  /* stateful */
} else if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Stateless.class)) {
  /* stateless */
} else {
  /* woops? */
}
```

Comment: Directly checking the proxy might  not work. I think you'd have to check the declared type of bound in case of a no-interface view. If it's an interface then it might be difficult to get this information.